# Django: how to get the value inside a querydict?

Tags: python, django, list, data-structures

I have the following querydict:

```
 <QueryDict: {'data_dict[user_id]': ['5'], 'data_dict[location]': ['Library'], 'data_dict[item_sold]': ['book']}>
```

I want to get the value by using the key: i.e (x = data_dict.get('user_id')

How can I do that? everytime I try to access the querydict it throws errors.

Comment: `data_dict.get['data_dict[user_id]']` but the problem seems to originate where you *constructed* this querydict.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you very much, it worked flawlessly :) My code is now: print(ajax_dict.get('data_dict[user_id]')

Comment: @MohammedBaashar you should not do that this way. How did you create that QueryDict?

Comment: @NixonSparrow a dict created in JAVASCRIPT and sent to django via AJAX: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: @MohammedBaashar so your dict should look like: `<QueryDict: {'user_id': '5', 'location': 'Library', ...>` or `<QueryDict: {'data_dict: {user_id': '5', 'location': 'Library', ...}}`. It matters how you pass values. If not now, you will probably understand that later on.